# When do baby teeth start falling out?

Tags: teeth

I am wondering when baby teeth begin falling out. I realize this varies from person to person but there has to be a general rule of thumb as to when it normally begins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually around age 6, but this varies a lot per children. According to this article from the Baby Center (often very helfup and reliable website), it can vary between age 4 and 7:
http://www.babycenter.com/0_losing-baby-teeth-what-to-expect-and-when_3658971.bc

Comment: Yep, incredibly variable. Ours were all between 4 and 6 when they started falling out, and our eldest still has a couple of baby teeth and he is nearly 13.

Comment: Sounds right to me; there's definitely a lot of variation - mine didn't start until 7, and I still had one left at 22.